# If $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, then $\left \| Ax \right \|=\left \| x \right \|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Is the following statement true or false: If $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, then we have that $\left \| Ax \right \|=\left \| x \right \|$.

---

I don't really understand this notation, I hope you can help me with this?
In our script I found that $\left \|  \right \|$ stands for norm (whatever is inside, norm of..).
So in this case we have the norm of a transformation matrix? Moreover I found that the norm of a vector is always $\geq 0$. If it equals zero, then the vector is the null vector.

We haven't got a vector here but I think we can apply that anyway. From what I have just written I deduce that $\left \| Ax \right \|=\left \| x \right \|$, we have that the transformation matrix is zero, else we wouldn't use equal sign here. And I don't see why this is the case when $A$ is an orthognal matrix, so I say the statement is false.

But I still don't understand it, maybe some can explain me please?

Comment: $Ax$ is a vector too, so $\| Ax \|$ is the norm of vector $Ax$.

Comment: @Evgeny was faster. :) 
I want to keep the comment to note that there are matrix norms, too. we usually denote them like so: the norm of $A$ is denoted $\left \| A \right \|$.

Comment: Can someone give answer pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$||x||^2 = x^Tx = x^T(A^TA)x = (Ax)^T(Ax) = ||Ax||^2$.

Comment: Is the first equality really true for all vector norms? Or just the Euclidian norm?

Comment: @wgrenard, it is the definition of Euclidean norm.

Comment: @Ennar Right I believe it would only work if you are talking about the Euclidian norm, but the question doesn't seem to specify we're working with the Euclidian norm. Hence my reason for asking :)

Comment: @wgrenard: Unitary transformations (so with an orthogonal matrix) preserve the Euclidean and Frobenius norm. (See: Numerical Linear Algebra - Trefethen & Bau).

Comment: @wgrenard, Euclidean norm is implicit here. An example is rotation by $45^\circ$ in $\Bbb R^2$. Clearly an isometry in Euclidean norm, but not in $1$-norm, for example. You can't expect that isometry in one norm will be isometry in some other.

Comment: @Ennar Ah, of course. Great example and makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

For any real matrix we have $$\langle Ax,y\rangle = \langle x,A^ty\rangle$$
Thus if $A$ is orthogonal, then

$$\|Ax\|^2 = \langle Ax, Ax\rangle = \langle x,A^tA x\rangle =\langle x,x\rangle = \|x\|^2$$